# Timestamp before 1970 is saved as 0000-00-00 00:00:00

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel

I have a timestamp column corresponding to model property.
But when I try to save a timestamp before 1970 in the table appears the value of `0000-00-00 00:00:00`.

Am I not using the appropriate format? Is `date` more suitable? Is there a workaround so I don't need to change my schema?

Comment: How are you saving that value?

Comment: `object->property = '1899-07-21 00:00:00';`

Comment: I don't know where object->property comes from, but before 1900 is certainly a lot earlier than before 1970.... if you're working with unix timestamps, then 1900 falls outside the supported range for 32-bit PHP

Comment: Indeed but that's the case with any date before 1970

Comment: First, are you talking about a database column of type timestamp, or a PHP timestamp value?

Comment: I am using a master record  layer so that string is saved in the table as date

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Unix epoch (or Unix time or POSIX time or Unix timestamp) is the number of seconds that have elapsed since January 1, 1970 (midnight UTC/GMT), not counting leap seconds (in ISO 8601: 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z).

If you're planning on using times that fall previous to that date, I recommend using a date field.

Answer (score 3):

Quoting from the [MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/datetime.html):

> The TIMESTAMP data type is used for values that contain both date and time parts. TIMESTAMP has a range of '1970-01-01 00:00:01' UTC to '2038-01-19 03:14:07' UTC.

Answer (score 1):

That is a real problem, but there is a nice work-around.

We know that concerning timestamps, the absolute 0 is in 1970. So, why do not we change our representation model and consider January 1st of 1970 to be the day Jesus has been born, namely January 1st of 1 AD. If you do that, then the year of 2000 would be represented by the number of 3970 (2000 + 1970). You could store dates like that and convert them when you view them or when you enter them.

Comment: I don't know how to do it. But I would rather change my schema than falsifying date occurrence.  Thank you for that hack info.

Comment: Also, as per another comment states, MySQL `timestamp` don't go further than approx. 2038.

Comment: @brclz interesting point. In that case one might want to store only values between 1970 and 2019 and have an int column for HalfCentury. The combination of the two would yield better results, but a date representation supporting all possible dates, including time values  as a new feature is to be preferred.